# ELIMINACION CON JQUERY ,PHP Y SWWETALERT2

Tags: jquery, laravel, sweetalert2

estoy intentado eliminar un registro con jquery y sweetalert2 , mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
$('#btnEliminar').click(function(e)
         {    
            // e.preventDefault();
                Swal.fire({
                  title: 'Estas Seguro?',
                  text: "Deseas Eliminar este Nodo?",
                  icon: 'warning',
                  showCancelButton: true,
                  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                  confirmButtonText: 'Si!'
                }).then((result) => {
                  if (result.isConfirmed) {
                     $('#btnEliminar').attr('href','/Crm/nodo/eliminar/'+idNodo);
                    //  $('#eliminar').trigger("click"); //ESTO LE DA CLICK SOLO
                  }
                })       
          
         });
```

ahora lo que intento hacer es que al darle ok ala alerta. este me modifique el href, y le agregue la url para eliminar el registro , pero en este caso solo me modifica el href pero no hace ninguna acción.mi pregunta es  como podrían hacer que de una vez este se ejecute y pueda eliminar el registro , muchas gracias .

Comment: sweetalert2 no sirve para hacer peticiones, para ello esta ajax, fetch, etc. Lo que tendrias que hacer es que dentro del `then` armar tu ajax. fetch. etc para hacer el envio, ya que solo estas agregando un atributo y nada mas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eliminar con confirmación puedes hacerlo de esta forma

```
<button id="bElim" type="button" class="btn btn-sm bg-danger text-white" onclick="rowElim(12);"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Eliminar</button>

function rowElim(id){
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Advertencia',
        text: "Desea eliminar este departamento?",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Si'
    }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
        $.ajax({                  
        type: "POST",
        url: "ruta_aqui",
        data: { 'id':id} 
        })
        .done(function (response) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Departamento Eliminado',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 700
            }).then((result) => {
                // redireccion con javascript
                //window.location.href = "Poner aqui ruta";
                //recargar página  jQuery
                location.reload();
            });
        })
    }

    });
}
```

Reemplaza la ruta de ajax por tu ruta.

Comment: Si te entiendo mi amigo . pero ahora si lo hago así no me va recargar la pagina y por ende no me va actualizar la tabla , por eso lo quise hacer de esa manera que me obligue a recargar la pagina.se podría ?

Comment: Si, se puede solo colocando un .then((result)) en la función de sweetalert, edite el código para que veas como funciona

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo lo solucione tal como me dijiste te lo agradezco !!!